# Concat tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, tags

I want to do something like this:

```
h* + p {
 color: red;
}
```

Instead of

```
h1 + p, h2+p... {
 color:red;
}
```

It is possible? (Dont find any solution yet)
I want to do it using only CSS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a preprocessor like Less or Sass .
In case you chose Sass , this is how you could do it in the sass file :
`@for $i through 6 {
    h.#{$i} + p {
    color:blue;
              }

}`

CSS in its own, is very limited!

Answer (score 0):

I see the question is quite old. Anyway, today something similar could be achieved through the :is pseudo-class, without using any preprocessor.

```css
:is(h1, h2, h3)+p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sic enim censent, oportunitatis esse beate vivere. Tu vero, inquam, ducas licet, si sequetur; Illa argumenta propria videamus, cur omnia sint paria peccata. Sit sane ista voluptas. Cur, nisi quod
  turpis oratio est? Quasi ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget.</p>

<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sic enim censent, oportunitatis esse beate vivere. Tu vero, inquam, ducas licet, si sequetur; Illa argumenta propria videamus, cur omnia sint paria peccata. Sit sane ista voluptas. Cur, nisi quod
  turpis oratio est? Quasi ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget.</p>

<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sic enim censent, oportunitatis esse beate vivere. Tu vero, inquam, ducas licet, si sequetur; Illa argumenta propria videamus, cur omnia sint paria peccata. Sit sane ista voluptas. Cur, nisi quod
  turpis oratio est? Quasi ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget.</p>
```

Also, check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ais) for further info about browsers support.